# how could i use my css style just in one page without the others?

Tags: css

I'm working with bootstrap  in some pages and without it in others but whene I merge two or 3 pages in one it affect the pages that i styled myself

```
<?php 
require_once('session.php');
confirm_logged_in();
?>
<? echo "je suis dans le gabarit admin"?>
<?php 
include('header.php');
include('menu.php');
?>
<div class='content'>
<?php echo $content;  ?>
</div>

<?php

include('footer.php');
?>
```

here it the exemple of my pages I use bootstrap in abonneList but not the others but when I reload the pages it change some things that I won't going to change in the header and the menu

Answer (score -1):

Add it at the end of your desired page rather than into the header.

```
<?php
require_once('session.php');

confirm_logged_in();

echo "je suis dans le gabarit admin";

include('header.php');
include('menu.php');
?>
<div class='content'>
    <?php echo $content; ?>
</div>
<!-- Add your custom stylesheet at the end of your desired page -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mycss.css" type="text/css" />
<?php
include('footer.php');
?>
```